# Can't able to create a Ceph bucket after deletion of access key

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, cloud, storage, ceph

Can't able to create a Ceph bucket after deletion of access key.
In my case whenever default access key is deleted it through an error

```
RGW REST API failed request with status code 403
(b'{"Code":"InvalidAccessKeyId","RequestId":"tx00000457ff5169168a9e3-00648afcd0'
b'-fdd1c2-dev","HostId":"fdd1c2-dev-*****"}').Why it is not creating Bucket from another access key available to it. Similar issue raised 2 years ago (https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/53671).
```

Similarly whenever user is deleted and we create new user same RGW invalid access key error occurred.

**Any solutions or steps to overcome this scenario.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.